# Powershell store variable in a hashtable and resolve the value later on

Tags: powershell, variables, reference

Let me start by saying I'm fairly certain I'm not using the correct terms, so please correct me where needed.

Here's the situation, I'm a ham radio operator and I have multiple radios that I program with different software (Chirp doesn't support all my radios).  Both applications have an *Export to CSV* option. When I export in Chirp, the column headers are:  Location, Name, Frequency, Tone, rToneFreq, cToneFreq.  When I export from RT Systems the column headers are (respectively): Channel Number, Name, Receive Frequency, Tone Mode, CTCSS, Rx CTCSS.  As you can see, several of the column headers do not match.

I have a Powershell script I wrote that imports the CSV (using the convertfrom-csv function so I can access the properties by name) so that I can compare entries to ensure that if I have the channel defined in multiple locations in the radio, everything is the same. Here's an example of the output:

```
Name = MANTIW
Freq = 146.720000
Tone = 100.0

Location Name   Frequency  Tone rToneFreq cToneFreq Comment

--------------------------------------------------

115      MANTIW 146.720000 Tone 100.0     100.0     Skyline ARC
392      GLNDLE 146.720000 Tone 100.0     100.0     Skyline & Sinbad link?
410      MANTIW 146.720000 Tone 100.0     100.0     Skyline ARC
```

This tells me, I have 146.720 with a tone of 100.0 defined for multiple channels where the name doesn't match.  I can then look and say that's ok or change the name as necessary.

Basically, for each item in my $csv var, I set the freq, tone, and name, then I say give me all of the entries in that var with the same freq and tone, then select unique names. If the count is greater than 1, write it to my file for review.

This is all working great. I used it with one radio and found lots of discrepancies to resolve.  Then I moved on to another radio that uses the RT Systems software to program and this is where my question came up.

I don't want to have separate scripts for each radio I have for maintenance reasons.  I already have the following code in my script to determine if the output is for one radio or the other:

```
if ($csv| Get-member | select-object -ExpandProperty Name | ? {$_ -eq  "Receive Frequency"}) {
    $radio = "A"

} elseif ($csv | Get-member | select-object -ExpandProperty Name | ? {$_ -eq "Frequency"}) {
    $radio = "B"
}
```

What I'm hoping to do is define some way to say if I'm using radio A, query for $*."Receive Frequency", but if I'm using radio B, query for $*.Frequency.  That way my queries below that point could remain the same and I wouldn't need custom queries for each radio.  I originally tried something like:

```
if ($csv| Get-member | select-object -ExpandProperty Name | ? {$_ -eq  "Receive Frequency"}) {
    $radio = "8600"
    $details = @{
        $freq = $_."Receive Frequency"
        $tone = $_.CTCSS
        $name = $_.Name
    }

} elseif ($csv | Get-member | select-object -ExpandProperty Name | ? {$_ -eq "Frequency"}) {
    $radio = "9800"
    $details = @{
        $freq = $_.Frequency
        $tone = $_.rToneFreq
        $name = $_.Name
    }
}
```

Then later down in the script where I set my tempFreq, tempTone, and tempName for each channel I'm processing, I just want to use:

```
    $tempFreq = $details["freq"]
    $tempTone = $details["tone"]
    $tempName = $details["name"]
```

Have that lookup to details and say oh get '$_.Frequency' since this is radio B.  I guess what I want to do is define a schema to say for this file/ radio, look at these properties for your information and for this other radio, look at these properties for the same information.

I'm probably overthinking this, I am known to do so.  Maybe it would be easier to write a couple of functions based on the radio type and just return everything as Freq and tone, but that would make it difficult to query later on for the unique values check.  Maybe I should just rename the column headers for radio B to match A and then I would only have a single script.  Anyways, I'm curious if there's a way to do what I want for the knowledge.  If not, there are definitely workarounds I can employ.

If you stuck with me this far, thanks for reading. I hope I made everything clear.

Comment: if I understand correct: I think you'd be better to normalize the values during input elaboration. As in: regardless the headers and values i the CSVs, you return an object with the same-names properties. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/VK0TKLhg     

If you are going to have many different types of CSVs, you might want to evaluate using Classes though.

Comment: Also note that the `ConvertFrom-Csv` commandlet has a `-Header` option so that you could standardize the header at the file level...

Answer (score 2):

Normalizing the input data is indeed the way to go - you just need to make sure you output your `$details` tables to be collected by a variable:

```
# Let's start by picking a "translation table" based on the input format
# No need for Get-Member, we can inspect the properties of the first object directly instead
if ($csv[0].psobject.Properties.Match('Receive Frequency')) {
  $columnMappings = [ordered]@{
    'freq' = 'Receive Frequency'
    'tone' = 'CTSS'
    'name' = 'Name'
  }
}
elseif ($csv[0].psobject.Properties.Match('Frequency')) {
  $columnMappings = [ordered]@{
    'freq' = 'Frequency'
    'tone' = 'rToneFreq'
    'name' = 'Name'
  }
}
else {
  Write-Warning "Unable to determine input format"
  return
}

# now let's process the input data
$freqEntries = @($csv |ForEach-Object {
  $cellValues = [ordered]@{}
  foreach ($columnHeading in $columnMappings.GetEnumerator()) {
    # use the key-value pair from the column translation table to fetch the correct property value by name
    $cellValues[$columnHeading.Key] = $_.$($columnHeading.Value)
  }

  # convert translated row entry to object and output
  [pscustomobject]$cellValues
})
```

`$freqEntries` will now hold an array of CSV entries with normalized property names `freq`, `tone` and `name`:

```
$freqEntries |Where-Object name -like 'MANTIW*'
# or 
$($freqEntries |Get-Random) |Select freq,name
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up normalizing my data, but I did it with if statements.  The reason I went this route was because sometimes a frequency will use a CTCSS code, but I have a few that still use DTCS codes so then I have to look at a different column.  So basically I build $CSV with standard columns depending on the data in each channel to normalize everything.  Thanks for the guidance!

```
if (($_.Tone -eq "Tone") -or ($_.Tone -eq "TSQL")) {
        $csv += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Channel = $_.Location
            Name = $_.Name
            Frequency = $_.Frequency
            Tone = $_.Tone
            txToneFreq = $_.rToneFreq
            recToneFreq = $_.cToneFreq
            Mode = $_.Mode
            Comment = $_.Comment
        }
    } elseif ($_.Tone -eq "DTCS") {
        $csv += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Channel = $_.Location
            Name = $_.Name
            Frequency = $_.Frequency
            Tone = $_.Tone
            txToneFreq = "D" + $('{0:d3}' -f [int]$_.DtcsCode)
            recToneFreq = "D" + $('{0:d3}' -f [int]$_.RxDtcsCode)
            Mode = $_.Mode
            Comment = $_.Comment
        }
    } elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Tone)) {
        $csv += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Channel = $_.Location
            Name = $_.Name
            Frequency = $_.Frequency
            Tone = $null
            txToneFreq = $null
            recToneFreq = $null
            Mode = $_.Mode
            Comment = $_.Comment
        }
    } else {
        Throw "Chirp Tone mode = $($_.Tone) unhandled"
    }
```